# Как в gulp работает слияние потоков (stream merge)

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-concat

Для процессинга CSS я использую gulp с autoprefixer и doIuse. Потребовалось добавить к стилям файл стороннего разработчика, причем так, чтобы он включался без изменений. Но в итоге все стили должны были упаковываться в один файл style.css, и для них должны были создаваться sourcemaps.

Я сделал так:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var plugins = getPlugins();

    var processors = [
        plugins.precss,
        plugins.autoprefixer,
        plugins.doiuse
    ];

    // мой css, должен пройти через autoprefixer
    var my_css = gulp.src([ ... my css files ... ])
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plugins.postcss(processors))
    ;

    // сторонний css, должен остаться как есть, но нужны sourcemaps
    var third_party = gulp.src([ ... third party css files ... ])
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    ;

    return plugins.merge2(third_party, my_css)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/css'))
    ;
});
```

Я не был уверен, что получится, но это сработало. Однако я так и не понял, как именно это работает? Почему после merge и concat правильно создаются sourcemaps?

Хотелось бы понять, как работает слияние потоков в gulp.